# Regex: how to find a comma between two quotation marks

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I need to find the dot between two quotation marks, and substitute it with a comma.

I'm trying with this

```
\".*?\"
```

but it finds everything between the quotation marks.

I need to transform something like this "100,21$" into this "100.21$"

Comment: What is the regex flavor? As the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) states, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.

Comment: Also, if you have currencies, you might just match the integer and fractional parts into groups, and then use backreferences. Are these strings standalone?

Comment: I'm using Sublimetext, I don't know how to use backreferences, I'll look for it!

Comment: Please see my answer, `"(\d*),(\d+)\$"` solution.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, your solution worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can *match* quoted substrings first with a

```
"[^"]+"
```

and then replace the `.` with `,` in the matched block (in a callback, or a post-process method/function).

Alternatively, you might use capturing + backreferences:

```
"(\d*),(\d+\$)"
```

to replace with `"$1.$2"` (where `$1` is the text captured with `(\d*)` and `$2` is the value captured with `(\d+\$)`). See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/fG6gQ3/3).

Answer (score -1):

If your string is simple like your exemple : `"100,21$"`
You can simple use this code :

```
str = str.replace(/,/g,'.');
```

If it's a little bit more complex like :

```
Here is an "example" of "100,21$" price, I am a string
```

You can use this :

```
str = str.replace(/"(\d+),(\d+)(.*?)"/g,'"$1.$2$3")
```

Regexr link if you want to test : 
http://regexr.com/3dbo5

nb : I wrote the example, but you can use the regexp and the string pattern in another langages

Comment: OP platform is not JavaScript.

Comment: Yes but you can use my JS pattern and string pattern in your code
I also make a regexr link : http://regexr.com/3dbo5